# Thread safe public string

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, ado.net

I have a public string that is set from data inside of a DataTable, i'm looking for an example on how to make it multithreading safe

```
public string Server { get; set; }

string Server = DT.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
```

This is what I have however, i don't think this is safe when all other threads set their string Server based on data inside of the datatable.

Comment: If each thread could have a different database value, which one SHOULD win? If they are all the same, then technically you are already safe because strings are thread safe because they are immutable. I would consider a design where only one thread is responsible for setting the string though (unless this is a lazy-loading model, then see my answer below)

Comment: What synchronization violation scenario are you afraid of?

Comment: In which way do you want it to be "thread safe", I believe strings are already thread safe because they're immutable, and I also think that assigning to and from a reference type is atomic already.

Comment: there should be no winner, each much use the string Server to connect to a specific server

Comment: I think you need to explain what the _expected_ behavior should be. Should all threads share `Server`? Should they have one each?

Comment: Furthermore `Server = DT.Rows[0].ItemArray[0]` is already atomic, wrapping it in a lock would accomplish nothing.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson the expected behavior is this String can be set and changed based on the dynamic value presented in the DataTable and then used accordingly within the thread

Comment: @Mike you say "no winner, each [must] use the string Server to connect to a specific server", by "specific" do you mean "unique"? If so, use thread local storage, and not a shared string.

Comment: Are you saying that each thread should have its own `Server`, or all threads should use the same `Server`?

Comment: @Matthew each thread should have it's own Server

Comment: You should check out http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1d42da/working-with-thread-local-storagetls-in-C-Sharp/  Thread Local Storage.

Comment: You should be asking yourself whether you really need a global variable here.  Global variables, even thread-local ones, are generally considered to be bad practice.  Have you looked into passing this as a parameter to the methods that need it?

Comment: @ChrisShain I agree. A local variable would solve the race conditions all around. If the design works for him to have it as a public property, then perhaps the ThreadLocal is what he wants. Also, if the container is created once per thread/server as well, then ThreadLocal isn't even needed as there would be a 1:1 ratio of threads to strings :)

Answer (score 5):

From your comments to your original post, I think what you want is [ThreadLocal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243.aspx)

You'd get:

```
// declared as:
ThreadLocal<string> Server;

// ... initialized by:
Server = new ThreadLocal(() => DT.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString());
```

In each thread the string here would be unique to that thread.

If you want the first thread to win (lazy load model) then use the following [Lazy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx)

```
// declared as:
Lazy<string> Server;

// ... initialized by:
Server = new Lazy(() => DT.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString());
```

In each thread the string here would be shared, and only the first thread would load it.

Comment: did you mean...
Server = new ThreadLocal<string>(() => DT.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString());

Comment: Yeah, I edited it right away, maybe even before you posted the comment :) Haha, but thank you.

Comment: @Mike as `void` means that a method has no return value, I don't understand the question. The method given to the `ThreadLocal` or `Lazy` constructors must be a Func, i.e., it must have a return value.